# Unique Custom field in Custom Field in Salesforce not getting created using metadata api

Tags: integration, c#

I am creating a unique custom field in Salesforce Lead Object
Here is the working code that i have written

```
            CustomField cf = new CustomField();
            cf.unique = true;
            cf.caseSensitive = false;
            cf.description = "Test"
            cf.fullName = "Lead" + "." + "test__c";
            cf.label = "test";
            cf.type = (SfApi.FieldType)Enum.Parse(typeof(SfApi.FieldType), 'Lead');
            AsyncResult r = _ms.create(new Metadata[] { cf })[0];
            while (!r.done)
            {
              System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1 * 1000);
              r = _ms.checkStatus(new string[] { r.id })[0];
            }
            if (r.state == AsyncRequestState.Error)
            {
              _log.Info("Error : " + r.statusCode + " " + r.message);
              return false;
            }
            else
            {
              _log.Info("Successfully created" );
            }
```

This created the required field in SF but its not unique . Any idea anyone.
Thnx in advance

Comment: Did you find out what was happening with this?